# How to get snow layer and underlying image behave fully responsive when first displayed in browser?

Tags: html, css, image, responsive, layer

Christmas is approaching, so I have installed a beautiful snow-script, as can be seen via [this link](https://www.bruedergrimmschule.de/archiv/weihnachtsmarkt/). In this example the script is installed in such a way that a complete page is covered with snow. This works perfectly. 
It is a matter of placing the following code just before the closing body-tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/ador_snow_p.js"></script>
<script>goAdorSnow('schnee', 100000, './wolken1.png', false, true, false, 0.7, 0.5, 0.4);</script>
```

and put some additional CSS and HTML-code on the page concerned.

However, when I want to apply this same script to one specific image on a different page, some additional code is needed. So in order:

- to set the correct size of the image involved;
- to get an overlay defined that adapts to any size of the image involved;
- and to get both image and overlay behave fully responsive when changing the browser-window,

I have used the following code:

```
<style>
.snow {
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    color: white;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 30%;
    margin-top: 0%;
    margin-right: 3%;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
    margin-left: 0%;
    float: left;
}
.container:hover > .overlay {
    opacity: 1;
}
</style>

<div class="container">
    <img src="https://www.aeternus.eu/images/krokussen_1600X1200.jpg" alt="thumb">
    <div class='snow' id="schnee" ></div>
</div>
```

This code is implemented on [this page-link](https://www.aeternus.org/snowscript/test-1/).

If you visit the above-mentioned link, you will notice that the snow-screen initially is displayed quite a lot above the related image. However, when changing the browser windows-size (using Windows Edge), you will see that the snow-overlay jumps to the image and from then on also stays there (as it should do!). This correct behaviour remains when the size of the browser-window is changed again. Please note: this works in Edge, not in Chrome.

Just to wrap it up: apart from the initial display/screen, everything seems to work fine.

Question: What should be changed in order to have the snow-layer immediately displayed correctly on the image, the moment that the page is loaded?

Comment: https://codepen.io/Richifg/pen/QWwNoeV 

https://codepen.io/bgutsol/pen/OJPNrWE

suggest use this scripts , they are full responsive

Comment: It would be ideal if the links in this could be deleted, since they will not last the test of time. Related reading: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: The first link is now broken (404).

Comment: link restored ...

Comment: Hi Piotr, both links are now broken.

Comment: both links restored now.

Comment: One of the links is broken yet again, and since the question sort of relies upon it (and since we have had a history of breakages) I am voting to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a good tip, I managed to solve this issue. Just before the closing bodytag, the following code needed to be added:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/ador_snow_p.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() { goAdorSnow('schnee', 100000, './wolken1.png', false, true, false, 0.7, 0.5, 0.4); });
</script>
```

Now the snow-script behaves fully responsive, independent of screen-size and browser-type.